# How to split list values into dictionary based on specified character?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list as below :

```
test1 = "['Identified Cost - Securities............ $ 8,038,909,658.20 ',
          'Identified Cost - Late Loan Fundings.... $ .00 ]"
```

What I need a dictionary as below :

```
"{Identified Cost - Securities : $ 8,038,909,658.20, 
  Identified Cost - Late Loan Fundings : $ .00}"
```

I have tried to convert it with following code:

```
def Convert(lst): 
    res_dct = {lst[i]: "" for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)} 
    return res_dct 
test2 = Convert(test1)
```

I got following dict.

```
{'Identified Cost - Securities............          $  8,038,909,658.20      ': '',
 'Identified Cost - Swaps.................                       $  .00      ': ''}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer:

---

```py
def convert(lst):
    res_dct = dict((line.rsplit('$')[0].replace('.', ''), '$' + line.rsplit('$')[1].rstrip()) for line in lst if line.rsplit('$'))
    return res_dct


test1 = ['Identified Cost - Securities............ $ 8,038,909,658.20 ',
         'Identified Cost - Late Loan Funding.... $ .00']

test2 = convert(test1)
```

Output:

```py
{'Identified Cost - Securities ': '$ 8,038,909,658.20', 'Identified Cost - Late Loan Funding ': '$ .00'}
```

Explanation:

---

You can approach the problem:

- 1. Split the string by '.':

```py
out = line.split(sep='.')
```

Result:

```py
['Identified Cost - Securities', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' $ 8,038,909,658', '20 ']
```

The first value will be our key.

- 2. From the original line, remove our key value

```py
line.replace(key, '')
```

Result:

```py
............ $ 8,038,909,658.20
```

- 3. Split the string by '$' and remove the right space

```py
8,038,909,658.20
```

If we combine them all, result:

```py
{'Identified Cost - Securities': '$  8,038,909,658.20', 'Identified Cost - Late Loan Funding': '$  .00'}
```

Code:

---

```py
def convert(lst):
    res_dct = {}

    for line in lst:
        out = line.split(sep='.')
        key = out[0]
        val = '$ ' + line.replace(key, '').split('$')[1].rstrip()
        res_dct[key] = val

    return res_dct


test1 = ['Identified Cost - Securities............ $ 8,038,909,658.20 ',
         'Identified Cost - Late Loan Funding.... $ .00']

test2 = convert(test1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the below code:

```
test1 = ['Identified Cost - Securities............ $ 8,038,909,658.20 ', 'Identified Cost - Late Loan Fundings.... $ .00']
# creating a dictionary to unpack the list and store the data as per you require
temp_dict = {}
for test in test1:
    temp = test.rsplit("$", 1)
    temp_dict.update({temp[0].strip(): ("$" + temp[1]).strip()})
```

Note: Split the list value based on the last occurrence of "$" and updated the dictionary with values stored at the 0th and 1st index position of the temp variable